# Bash profile alias giving unexpected EOF and syntax errors

Tags: keyboard, osx-mavericks, bash

I'm trying to add the following alias in my .bash_profile in TextEdit in Mavericks (10.9.3) on a Mac Mini:

```
alias proj="cd ~/documents/google\ drive/web/projects"
```

I get the following errors:

```
line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'

line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

bash gives:

```
alias proj='"cd'
```

However, if I copy & paste the exact same line from Notepad in my Windows VM into TextEdit it works..

bash now gives as expected:

```
alias proj='cd ~/documents/google\ drive/web/projects'
```

I've tried the following with no success:

- Different paths with and without spaces
- Swapped the Dell PC keyboard I was using for a Mac
- Changed language to British English from British
- Installed all updates

I can get round it using copy & paste as above, but would really like to get to the bottom of it. Any ideas much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That's strange. Have you tried with `$HOME` instead of `~` ?

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that unfortunately. It's something to do with double quotes, if I copy & paste and then remove the last " and re-enter it, it errors. If I were to replace ~ with $HOME for example it would work after copy & pasting, but not if you type from scratch..

Comment: Is "google drive" a symbolic link or some other kind of link? Using regular folders, I duplicated this path on my machine, and the alias works fine with single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It is a quoting problem.  Try:

```
alias proj="cd ~/documents/'google drive'/web/projects"
```

when eval-ing the alias command, the double quotes are removed.
When processing the "proj" invocation, the single quotes are removed.
Your original backslash was removed at alias evaluation time.
You could also double the backslashes:

```
alias proj="cd ~/documents/google\\ drive/web/projects"
```

Works for me.  Turn on command tracing (set -x) and see what really happens.

```
$ cat xx ; source xx ; proj ; pwd
alias proj="cd $HOME/workspace/'google drive'/web"
/home/sciadmin/workspace/google drive/web
```

P.S. I sanity checked the equivalence of "$HOME" and "~" as an alias.  Works fine, so replacing $HOME with ~ will work in the above example.

OK, here's the results for a symlink:

```
$ . xx ; cat xx ; proj ; pwd ; pwd -P
alias proj="cd ~/workspace/'google drive'/web"
/home/sciadmin/workspace/google drive/web
/home/sciadmin/workspace/foo bar/web
```

I think you may not be using BASH.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work even with copy & pasting and gives the 2 errors above.

Comment: It _is_ bash you are using, correct?  Type "echo $BASH_VERSION" at your command prompt to be sure.

Comment: Yes I am Bruce, version is 3.2.51(1). I think it's to do with either my text editor or the bash_profile file, I've just been using bash only to create the alias and it seems fine, no errors.. Will keep investigating, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's TextEdit that's the issue, I've just edited the profile in VIM and it's fine so I'll use that for the time being. Would like to know why though.. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: @SteveTyler TextEdit may be using "smart quotes", i.e. replacing the plain double-quotes you type with fancy unicode quotes -- which the shell doesn't recognize and treats as regular characters. (Actually, from the error, I think it might've just swapped one of the two into a fancy quote, leaving the other unmatched.)

Answer (score -1):

I had some issues with textedit and bash.   Check textedit preferences 'GENERAL' and select plain text, then turn off smart quotes and smart dash.

If that doesn't do it - then, sadly, I am Sans Clue.

Comment: Many thanks Keith, changed the preferences and it's all ok now.